# Persist a MPMediaItemCollection Object Using NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults, mpmediaitemcollection

How do you persist a MPMediaItemCollection object using NSUserDefaults? The MPMediaItemCollection object is a single song selected from the iPod.

I have been struggling with this for hours! Anyone have any ideas or alternatives to NSUserDefaults or a conversion from MPMediaItemCollection, or anything?!

Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to persist MPMediaItemCollection objects? (selected from iPod)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247315/way-to-persist-mpmediaitemcollection-objects-selected-from-ipod)

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark at it as correct.

Comment: cool. That works well. You should take credit for it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First convert/encode the MPMediaItemCollection to an NSData Object and store it using NSUserDefaults using:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:mediaItemCollection];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"someKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

From there, you can decode and use anywhere else in your app....

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"someKey"];
MPMediaItemCollection *mediaItemCollection = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```