# How to persist an MPMediaItemCollection?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsuserdefaults, mpmediaitem, mpmediapickercontroller

I'm developing an app where I let the user to create a playlist by using the `MPMediaPickerController`. I'd like to be able to save this playlist, and I've been looking for posts dealing with this issue, but I'm not sure if the solutions I've read are actually the only or the best... for example, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248821/persist-a-mpmediaitemcollection-object-using-nsuserdefaults) explains how to save the `MPMediaItemCollection` items into the `NSUserDefaults`: is it really necessary to save the `MPMediaItem`s? Isn't there a "lighter" way? And for this scenario, what should it be better: persisting in `Core Data` or in `NSUserDefaults`?

Thanks in advance